# firefox resolution is not correct

Tags: linux, firefox

I use `xrandr -s 1920x1080` to change screen resolution and it worked.But when I open my firefox and run `alert(screen.width)`, I find it not equal to my expected value. What could be the reason?

My os is Debian 3.14.7-1 (2014-06-16) x86_64 GNU/Linux
firefox version is 38.3.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question's description is wrong.
Actually I solved it by change the command 
    `$ xrandr -o right`
to
    `$ xrandr --output HDMI --rotate right`